# Ajax refresh in other tab unbinds selectize element from edit form Rails 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a Rails 5.1 app with multiple views.  The main view is the calls index view in which I do an ajax refresh of the partials and use a callback to re-initialize the `selectize` JS element in my calls/index view like so:

```
<h4>All Calls</h4>
<%= form_tag calls_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= select_tag "region", options_from_collection_for_select(Region.all, :id, :name, selected: @region), prompt: "All Regions" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Select Region", :name => nil, :class => 'btn btn-sm btn-info' %>
<% end %>
<hr>
<div id="active">
  <%= render "assigned" %>
</div>

<div id="inactive">
  <%= render "unassigned" %>
</div>


<script>
  $(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
      $.getScript('/calls/?region=<%= params[:region] %>')
      .done(function(script, textStatus) {
        $('.selectize').selectize();
      })
    }, 15000);
  });
</script>
```

This works just fine in the calls/index view and no problems occur.  But if I edit a new call in another tab (same session) the edit view will present and there are selectize elements within the form.  When the ajax refreshes the calls/index view in the other tab the edit form selectize fields will unbind and I have to refresh the form to get them back.

This is before the ajax refreshes:
[image]

This is after the ajax refreshes:
[image]

I'm pretty sure that it's unbinding the `selectize` element, but not sure how to get around this or if I have some bug in my code.  The edit form is a standard rails `form_for`, nothing special, just a view.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack answer, but it worked.  In the form on the edit view, I changed my selectors to `select` and initialized `selectize` in `application.js` like so:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('.select').selectize();
});
```

Not sure why the selector element clobbered itself but renaming it fixed the issue.